# PHP white screen on IS NOT NULL MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am having a problem with PHP getting TEXT data from a database. The data in question are JSON running routes that I have exported from a share.mapbbcode.org, so I can plot them on OSM maps for personal tracking.

I am attempting to make a master map that shows all the routes I have ran in the past, and to do this I will loop through each row in my table where RunGeoJSON is populated with the JSON coordinates of the run route, while ignoring columns where there is no data. (I already have a table set up where from the table I can do a POST w/ the JSON coordinates, but the difference is this table displays all rows in the database as I am also displaying other rows in that table (Weight, Run/Walk distance,  Cycling distance, etc.)

JSON coordinates are formated as follows in the database:

> [[-94.8472,38.97746],[-94.84675,38.97778],[-94.84418,38.97804],[-94.84401,38.98732],[-94.84396,38.99436],[-94.84231,38.99434],[-94.84205,38.99459],[-94.8419,38.99904],[-94.83943,38.99909],[-94.83948,39.01235],[-94.83928,39.01417],[-94.83931,39.01693],[-94.83978,39.01682],[-94.83935,39.01658],[-94.83847,39.01655],[-94.83785,39.01645],[-94.83727,39.01602],[-94.83654,39.01563],[-94.83587,39.01497],[-94.83523,39.015],[-94.83474,39.01557],[-94.83424,39.01568],[-94.83358,39.01587],[-94.833,39.01567],[-94.83201,39.01513],[-94.83119,39.01483],[-94.83064,39.015],[-94.8304,39.01597],[-94.82993,39.01645],[-94.82909,39.01657],[-94.82798,39.01677],[-94.83542,39.04099],[-94.8357,39.04054],[-94.83737,39.0404],[-94.83808,39.0402],[-94.84506,39.04104]]

Somehow it appears PHP is not properly returning results when the query ignores null rows. I know PHP can read the data based on the fact that the afformentioned table allows me to fetch and $_POST the GeoJSON coordinates to another document.

```
<?php include '/ASWebUI/Templates/Header.php'; // Database connectivity established here
$query = "SELECT RunGeoJSON FROM Fitness WHERE RunGeoJSON IS NOT NULL;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<p/>" . $row['RunGeoJSON']; // Should output the [[Lat,Lon],[...]] coordinates
} ?>
```

MySQL returns 9 rows populated as desired with the same query cut & paste into mysql command prompt, so the query is not defective.

Unfortunately, this is not working and instead I am getting a blank screen, with no errors when I put the error reporting on.

Furthermore, when I attempted to do mysqli_fetch_assoc, I got "NULL" returned, so somehow this query is not fetching data.

All other queries (which I have many) run fine.

Update 6/9/2014

Still not having any luck. I switched to PDO MySql and no better luck.

```
$stmt_RGJ = $dbpdo -> prepare("SELECT RunGeoJSON FROM Fitness WHERE RunGeoJSON IS NOT NULL;");
$stmt_RGJ -> execute();
while ($row_RGJ = $stmt_RGJ -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<br/>" . $row_RGJ['RunGeoJSON'];
}
```

PHP prior to the query works fine, it's just the query that doesn't work in PHP when it does in Console. Not sure what's going on - unless PHP doesn't know how to handle a MySQL query with IS NOT NULL. Query using GetGeoJSON combined with other fields in the same table (not using IS NOT NULL) in another page works fine, as well.

Comment: try debugging with print_r(), dumping $con, $query and $result in there like print_r(array("con" => $con, "query" => $query, "result" => $result);

Comment: Any messages in the server log or perhaps in the source code of your white screen?

Comment: print_r(array("con" => $con, "query" => $query, "result" => $result,  "row" => $row));
==== PHP output below ====
Array ( [con] => [query] => SELECT RunGeoJSON FROM Fitness WHERE RunGeoJSON IS NOT NULL; [result] => [row] => )

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer and it had nothing to do with the query or PHP at all. It's because I had placed the PHP file in a subfolder, and while I did reference my "Header.php" with the relative path, the Header.php file had relative path's to Header.php location, which means all the JavaScript files I needed were not being located properly. DOH!